# How to check value null in ruby on rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have create new array jobs and `j.id` is start from 423 and loop creates array index from 0 to total job ids with null value from 0 to 422 id. So my question is how to set condition to check the null value of j.name?

```
@jobs = []
demo.demojobs.each do | j |
    if j.name != null #condition 
        @jobs[j.id] = j.name
    end
end
```

I am working on rails version 3.2.11

Output:

```
pipe
0: null
1: null
.
.
.
.
423:    "jobname"
424:    "jobname"
425:    "jobname"
426:    "jobname"
427:    "jobname"
```

Comment: From reading comments you want output in an array or hash ?

Comment: @ts I want output in array

Comment: Can you please format your array as `423 "jobname"` is weird array it can be `['423 jobname',  424 jobname]`

Comment: If your output array is like `['423 jobname', '424 jobname']` check my updated answer hope it helps

Comment: What is the actual input here? Is this data that you are fetching from a database query?

Answer (score 2):

`nil` value is interpreted as false in conditions, so you can write:

```
@jobs = []
demo.demojobs.each do | j |
    if j.name 
        @jobs[j.id] = j.name
    end
end
```

or in a more concise manner:

```
@jobs = []
demo.demojobs.each do | j |         
  @jobs[j.id] = j.name if j.name
end
```

You can also use [`#nil?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/NilClass.html#method-i-nil-3F) method if you want to check explicitly:

```
@jobs = []
demo.demojobs.each do | j |
    if !j.nil? 
        @jobs[j.id] = j.name
    end
end
```

There is a nice blogpost explaining various options: https://blog.arkency.com/2017/07/nil-empty-blank-ruby-rails-difference/

Comment: I have try all conditions but still same issue array start from 0 index.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand that problem with 0 index, could you tell more about it?

Comment: I have j.id which is start from 423 so i want array create from 423 index not from 0 index.

Comment: What is your output now with answers you have tried ?

Answer (score 1):

it's `nil` in Ruby, not `null`
You can check if an object is `nil` by calling `present?` or `blank?`.

```
j.name.present?
```

this will return `false` if the name is an empty string or `nil` .

or you can use

```
j.name.blank?
```

Answer (score 1):

> how to set condition to check the null value of j.name?

There are many ways to check for null/`nil` or an empty string in ruby

1. [present?](https://apidock.com/rails/Object/present%3F)  This will return true or false

   ```
   j.name.present?
   ```
2. [blank?](https://apidock.com/rails/Object/blank%3F)  This is opposite of `present?`

   ```
   j.name.blank?
   ```
3. `j.name == nil`
4. `empty?` can be used on strings, arrays and hashes.

**Edit:**

```
@jobs = {}
#in your loop
@jobs[j.id] = j.name if j.name #you can use any condition here to check nil
```

Comment: 423, 424 are index of array not a value with jobname i need output like 423: jobname.

Comment: array index can not be start from 423 if you want like this you can use hash instead of array `@jobs = {423: 'jobname', 424: 'jobname'}` like this

Answer (score 0):

You can use `present?` or `blank?` in condition. Your code should be

```
if j.name.present? #condition 
   @jobs[j.id] = j.name
end
```